# How do you generate a random number in swift?

Tags: swift, random

**tl:dr; How do I generate a random number, because the method in the book picks the same numbers every time.**

This seems to be the way in Swift to generate a random number, based on the book released from Apple.

```
protocol RandomNumberGenerator {
    func random() -> Double
}
class LinearCongruentialGenerator: RandomNumberGenerator {
    var lastRandom = 42.0
    let m = 139968.0
    let a = 3877.0
    let c = 29573.0
    func random() -> Double {
        lastRandom = ((lastRandom * a + c) % m)
        return lastRandom / m
    }
}
let generator = LinearCongruentialGenerator()

for _ in 1..10 {
    // Generate "random" number from 1-10
    println(Int(generator.random() * 10)+1)
}
```

The problem is that in that for loop I put at the bottom, the output looks like this:

```
4
8
7
8
6
2
6
4
1
```

The output is the same every time, no matter how many times I run it.

Comment: I looked at the other comments, and they were actually just copying and pasting what was in the book.

Comment: look at the answers in the other question. they are a lot simpler than this and don't require a seed

Comment: Yup.  I'm deleting this question since it was duplicated.  arc4random() is much simpler.  Sorry!  -- edit, can't delete because there are answers.  Oh well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The random number generator you created is not truly random, it's *psueodorandom*.

With a psuedorandom random number generator, the sequence depends on the seed. Change the seed, you change the sequence.

One common usage is to set the seed as the current time, which usually makes it random enough.

You can also use the standard libraries: `arc4random()`. Don't forget to `import Foundation`.

Comment: It's not really pseudorandom. It's pretty darn deterministic.

Comment: I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'arc4random'" when I try to call arc4random() in the playground. How do I use the standard lib?

Comment: Seems to work if you `import Foundation`

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, I'm not sure that you could find a pseudorandom number generator that isn't "pretty darn deterministic".

Comment: @DanHixon You'd have to import it... Setting the seed to the current time would work better.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta This is how most random number functions are implemented. Surprised me once, but not anymore.

Comment: @zneak: Well, ok, I'm talking about the code the OP has posted, which is lacking a (non-fixed) seed.

Comment: @AnubianNoob: random number functions require a non-fixed seed to work properly.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta That is a problem... You can change one of M, A, and C...

Answer (score 0):

Pseudorandom number generators need a "seed" value. In your case, if you change `lastRandom` with any number, you'll get a different sequence.